# Complex Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have and containing object named: Flight

it contains:

```
List<Segement> Segements
List<Passenger> Pax      
List<Award> Awards
```

as each award contains:

```
List<Segment> Segements
Passenger Pax
```

I want to check for all combinations of Segements and Pax (taken from the Flight obj) and then compare them to the existing combination within each Award.
So that finally I will get a list of Awards whose combination do not exist in any award object

I wonder how to do that in one linq query

Comment: Aren't segment and pax list seperate? What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: each passenger can have more than one segement in each award. An Award is a combination of a passenger and his Segements. The flight contains all the passengers and all the segements available. I want to get all the combinations possible of segements and passengers which do not appear in any award

Comment: But Segement(?) and Pax have nothing in common. They are in different lists. How do you decide which segement belongs to which passenger? Can you explain what a Segement is?

Comment: Provide some example data that shows us what you want to do, it is not 100 % clear.

Comment: Each award contains that - a Pax has his Segements

Comment: Example: Segements in flight object - TLV-JFK, JKF-TLV and 3 Pax : Guy, Dave, Jean. One award - contains TLV-JFK / Jean. I want to find all the other options which are no "awarded" like TLV-JKF/Dave,JFK-TLV/Jean etc

Comment: Shouldn't your award object have one segment instead of many?

Comment: Not neseceraly, each pax can travel more than one Segement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    var flight = new Flight();
    var x = from s in flight.Segements
            from p in flight.Pax
            select new
    {
        Pax = p ,
        Segemnt = s
    };

    var y = from a in flight.Awards
            from s in a.Segements
            select new
    {
        Pax = a.Pax,
        Segemnt = s
    };

    var result = x.Except(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this single query will product the desired result:

```
var query = 
    from f in flights
    from p in f.Pax
    from s in f.Segements
    from a in f.Awards
    where !((a.Pax.Name == p.Name) && (a.Segements.Select(_ => _.Id).Contains(s.Id)))
    select new Award { Pax = p, Segements = new[] { s } };
```

Obviously, I made some assumptions on how to identify individual passengers and segments. Also, I'd be very surprised if this query worked as-is when querying an entity framework data source directly.